# Choose what field show when depth level is 2

Tags: cakephp-2.1

In CakePHP I have prepared a Json webservice. This is an excerpt of what I get:

```
{
   Offices:[
      {
         Office:{
            id:"1",
            Company:{
               id:"1",
               name:"ABC Software"
            }
         },
         Person:{
            mail:"sASa@sAAsS.it",
            OfficePersonTask:[
               {
                  office_id:"1",
                  person_id:"1",
                  task_id:"1"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

What I want is the possibility to show only some field from relative database, so the method that query the database have `$options['fields']` properly setting, so if I want to show person's mail I write:

```
$options['fields'] = array("Person.mail");
```

but what if I want to show company's id or company's name whice is one level deeper?

Answer (score 0):

If there are associations between the models you should be ably to do it with:

```
$options['fields'] = array('Person.mail','Company.id','Company.name');
```

Actually it doesn't matter that "Company is one level deeper". This goes right in the SELECT clause like: (Note that SQL primer is an example)

```
SELECT Person.mail, Company.id, Company.name 
FROM Persons AS p
LEFT JOIN Company AS c ON p.company_id = c.id
```